# Shell script curl outputs progress on stderr

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I've redirected a script `stdout` and `stderr` into different log files like this:

```
bash run.sh > out.log 2>err.log &
```

I've some `curl` requests in my script that outputs progress state into `stderr` like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   210  100   210    0     0    294      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   294
```

This makes the log files full of useless data. How can I disable this, so that I can assume stderr would have only errors.

Comment: To any tool writers, please take this question as yet another data point to support the (often ignored) long time best practice: succeed quietly, fail loudly.  That this progress banner is on by default instead of only activated by `--verbose` or similar is an atrocity.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah I didn't even expect the progress to be logged into "error channel"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `curl -s` (or `--silent`) to suppress the progress bar. Add `-S` (or `--show-error`) to still get error messages printed to stderr.

Comment: @amirz98: Unfortunately, there are only 2 standard output handles, stdout and stderr. Maybe they should've created stdwarn and stdinfo, too, but they didn't.